# I'm trying to use mysql for multi guild for discord.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a multi guild command and I tried to make it but it kept get errors as you can see here is my code I'm using:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
 client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
  connection.query(
   `SELECT prefix FROM guilds where guildID = '${guild.id}' AND ownerID = '${guild.ownerID}'`,
   function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results[0].prefix);
   }
  );
 });
});
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Looks like you have a missing semi-colon at the end of the `client.guilds` section.

Comment: If you're getting errors, it would make sense to tell us what they are

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved it :D

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    connection.query(`SELECT prefix FROM guilds where guildID = '${guild.id}' AND ownerID = '${guild.ownerID}'`, function (error, result, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      prefixx.set(guild.id, result[0].prefix);
    });
  });
});
```